Why does BaseX XQuery result format change when I wrap the results in a new element?
I'm building up an XQuery piece by piece in the BaseX editor (my first XQuery attempt). At the last step, the result format changed and I don't understand why. I am really having a hard time with XQuery syntax (book on order). I had expected a "pretty print" view as had been returned on all the steps leading up the to the end, but the view changed.
This XQuery script:
for $pc in /fhx/batch_equipment_phase_class
let $pc_name := $pc/@name
return
  for $fb in $pc/phase_class_algorithm/function_block[@name != 'FAIL_MONITOR']
  let $fb_name := $fb/@name
  return
    for $step in /fhx/function_block_definition[@name = $fb/@definition]/sfc_algorithm/step
    let $step_name := $step/@name
    return
      for $action in $step/action
      let $action_name := $action/@name
      return
        (<phase_class>{data($pc_name)}</phase_class>,
        <fb>{data($fb_name)}</fb>,
        <step>{data($step_name)}</step>,
        <action>{data($step_name)}</action>,
        $action/*)

gives an output like this:
<phase_class>4_AC25_CIPSU</phase_class>
<fb>RUN_LOGIC</fb>
<step>CLEAR_INT_BYP</step>
<action>CLEAR_INT_BYP</action>
<description>Step Message.</description>
<action_type>ASSIGN</action_type>
<qualifier>P</qualifier>
<expression>'^/STEP_MSG.CV' := "Clearing Interlock Bypasses";</expression>
<delay_time>0</delay_time>

But modifying to add the <row> element wrapper:
for $pc in /fhx/batch_equipment_phase_class
let $pc_name := $pc/@name
return
  for $fb in $pc/phase_class_algorithm/function_block[@name != 'FAIL_MONITOR']
  let $fb_name := $fb/@name
  return
    for $step in /fhx/function_block_definition[@name = $fb/@definition]/sfc_algorithm/step
    let $step_name := $step/@name
    return
      for $action in $step/action
      let $action_name := $action/@name
      return
      <row>
        <phase_class>{data($pc_name)}</phase_class>
        <fb>{data($fb_name)}</fb>
        <step>{data($step_name)}</step>
        <action>{data($step_name)}</action>
        {$action/*}
      </row>

it changes to this:
<row><phase_class>4_AC25_CIPSU</phase_class><fb>RUN_LOGIC</fb><step>CLEAR_INT_BYP</step><action>CLEAR_INT_BYP</action><description>Step Message.</description><action_type>ASSIGN</action_type><qualifier>P</qualifier><expression>'^/STEP_MSG.CV' := "Clearing Interlock Bypasses";</expression><delay_time>0</delay_time></row>

I expected this:
<row>
   <phase_class>4_AC25_CIPSU</phase_class>
   <fb>RUN_LOGIC</fb>
   <step>CLEAR_INT_BYP</step>
   <action>CLEAR_INT_BYP</action>
   <description>Step Message.</description>
   <action_type>ASSIGN</action_type>
   <qualifier>P</qualifier>
   <expression>'^/STEP_MSG.CV' := "Clearing Interlock Bypasses";</expression>
   <delay_time>0</delay_time>
</row>

Please help me understand why the format changes and what syntax I should be using to get the output format I had expected.

By default, descendant nodes of XML are not indented. You change change this by prepending the following output declaration to your query:
declare option output:indent 'yes';


Thank you, that worked. Was there some reason each element was on its own line with the first code example even without this line?

Yes: The first example created multiple indepent results, whereas the second one created a single result with child elements. The specification requires whitespace to be unchanged within single results. Which is confusing indeed, as the indenting whitespace that is part of your original XQuery expression is ignored and not added to the result.
